# React Native null is not an object (evaluating 'LoginManager.logInWithPermissions')

Tags: react-native, expo, facebook-login

When I try to login to Facebook it gives me this error

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'LoginManager.logInWithPermissions')
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:104:6 in reportException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:171:19 in handleException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/setUpErrorHandling.js:24:6 in handleError
at node_modules/expo-error-recovery/build/ErrorRecovery.fx.js:12:21 in ErrorUtils.setGlobalHandler$argument_0
at [native code]:null in flushedQueue
at [native code]:null in invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue
```

[image]
[image]

Im calling the function like this:

```
import {View} from "react-native";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  LoginManager,
} from "react-native-fbsdk-next";


               <View style={styles.horisontalView}>
                  <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() => {
                      LoginManager.logInWithPermissions([
                        "public_profile",
                        "email",
                      ]).then(
                        function (result) {
                          if (result.isCancelled) {
                            console.log("Cancelado");
                          } else {
                            console.log(
                              "Login realizado con permisos: " +
                                result.grantedPermissions.toString()
                            );
                          }
                        },
                        function (error) {
                          console.log("Error en Login: " + error);
                        }
                      );
                    }}
                  >
                  </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
```

installed by following this instructions: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fbsdk-next

Comment: Did you ever solve this @Ligia? I'm hitting the same issue on Android only after upgrading to RN .63.4.

Comment: I dont really remember how it got fixed but I have the code like this now:
  ```const signFB = () => {
    LoginManager.logInWithPermissions(['public_profile', 'email']).then(
      login => {
        if (login.isCancelled) {
          setLoadFalse();
        } else {
          AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(data => {
            const token = data?.accessToken.toString();
            if (token) getInfoFromToken(token);
          });
        }
      },
      error => {
        console.error(error);
      },
    );
  }```